# How do I use relative dates in M to compare dates

Tags: powerbi, m

I have a table of contracts:

```
Machine    Enrollment#     StartDate     EndDate
A          12345           1/1/2019      1/1/2020
B          25864           5/30/2009     1/1/2016
C          98765           6/15/2018     6/15/2021
B          12586           1/2/2016      1/1/2021
```

I want to be able to filter my table in the query editor using M code to only show contracts that were active as of last month. So, I need something like:

```
EndDate > StartofMonth(LastMonth())
```

But I don't believe those function exist. I used to have:

```
EndDate > #date(Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()), Date.Month(DateTime.LocalNow())-1,1)
```

But now that it is the first month of a new year this function does not work because it is looking for December 2020 which has not occurred yet. Seems like it should be an easy fix but I am stuck. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You can use this piece of code to get the first date of last month. Date.StartOfMonth(Date.AddMonths(DateTime.LocalNow(), -1))

Comment: That's it! Thank You